# Erratum to correct a reference — will this technically work?

Tags: citations, errors-erratum

Hours after I approved the proofs, I noticed a key reference in my article was wrong.  Authors and title are correct, journal is wrong, and it's wrongly listed as *in press*.  The paper is now published (it's a fast journal, the status is now *registering DOI*), so the reference probably can't be changed anymore.  I could submit an erratum, but would this be "picked up" by services such as Scopus or Google Scholar?

Related from a different perspective: *[Miswritten reference in (in press) paper](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/103103/1033)*

Comment: How bad is it? If it's a minor typo then I wouldn't worry about it too much. Most bibliographies I read through have at least one typo. If it's still possible to find the article using the reference, then it's doing what it's meant to.

Comment: Put a technical report online that corrects the mistake (e.g., on a personal website, departmental page, arXiv, ...)

Comment: @Spark Wrong journal and incorrectly noted as "in press" when it's actually published, but someone googling title will find it.

Comment: In press vs actually published is forgivable, after all you could’ve seen the article when it was in press. How wrong a journal name?

Comment: @Spark I used 'RS' in my bibtex source and I have a list of journal abbreviations, I didn't pay attention that 'RS' was referring to 'Radio Science' rather than 'Remote Sensing'...